# Getting banned from triage review for a long time that does not make any sense

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

The duration of suspension from triage review seems absolutely disproportionate.

[image]

This type of harsh reaction and long suspension from doing something one only does out of generosity, and because he is fond of community on his/her own valuable time that could be put for something else, feels like a punishment! It is absolutely demotivating.

Feeling sorry for the SO.

**UPDATE**

Lifting quality of the posts requires a fair amount of energy and concentration. This system is far from what it should be, be it bad labeling of buttons, be it not notifying the reviewer about a ban promptly, etc., I prefer not to waste my time any more.

**UPDATE 2**

**MODERATOR: DO NOT DELETE MY NOTES & UPDATES**

Comment: Since it looks like it took you more than  a month to notice ban (as review and likely the ban happened on Mar 23 - https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25668644) it sounds like quite reasonable length of ban so you had a good chance to notice it. There is also non-zero chance that it is not your first ban, but my understanding it is hard to figure out from your account view...

Comment: You were previously banned on March 8th, and evidently didn't see the message. As Alexei said, *this* ban was put into place on March 23rd, and it seems you're only *just now* seeing the message, after more than a month. So yes, this is why the ban duration is very long, to ensure that you actually *see* the message and *learn* why your decision was wrong.

Comment: "This [...] feels like a punishment!" I mean... it *is* a punishment?

Comment: @F1Krazy It makes sense to interpret it that way. But the primary purpose of review bans is *not* punishment. Review bans serve two purposes: (1) to inform/educate the user that they have been reviewing incorrectly, and (2) to stop them from reviewing temporarily (and thus making any more mistakes) until they understand #1.

Answer (score 7):

You've been impacted by a couple of things coming together all at once.

The triage queue has a button labeled "Requires Editing", but it should read "Requires Editing that could be done by someone other than the OP"; The "Unsalvageable" button should read "OP needs to provide more information, or question is off topic, or spam". Well, except for there being no mechanism to trigger the OP to be notified about what needs improvement other than just closing their question.

Then to top that off the software for the site doesn't do a good job of showing you when you've been "review suspended" so you can learn from your mistakes.

The last element is that you likely made your first few reviews in the triage queue, and the suspension script was run on you as many times in a row as you had chosen "Requires Editing" even though that message only shows you the latest.

If you message the moderator who "review suspended" you explaining that you now know what those buttons are for and that the labels don't match it is likely the suspension will be lifted.